# Not able to access global variable set in beforeLaunch in onprepare when shardTestFiles is true

Tags: protractor

In Protractor, I am not able to fetch the global variable set in beforeLaunch in onPrepare.
This happens when shardTestFiles is set to true .
Is there any way in which a global variable set in beforeLaunch can be accessed in onPrepare while executing multiple instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. If you want a common folder then define a variable with the path of common folder in your onPrepare function. Then provide the common path to the reporter that you are using.

Refer [this](http://timothymartin.azurewebsites.net/protractor-before-and-afters/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want a common folder, the name of which is dynamic based  on time stamp. If I try to  do this in onprepare, each instance would create separate folders as the timestamp would be slightly different for each instance. I am looking to set that folder name globally in something which runs only once like beforelaunch and then refer to it. The value i set in beforeLaunch, is not accessible from onPrepare. is there a way to do this?